# VScode: Automating conversion of python file to Jupyter notebook with a task

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

In VScode I can write a python file with markdown and python cells and then convert it to a notebook via the command palette. Everything works well, but I would like to automate this with a task.

I know I could just define a shortcut for the conversion but then I would still need to manually save the notebook with the file explorer. Can I automate this with a task? If so how do I access the function for the conversion? Is this some internal function of VScode or can I access this function via the command line?

I tried a few things with the Jupyter command in the command line but didn't have any luck. Also I could not find a comprehensive documentation for the Juypter command.

Another question in regards to Jupyter notebooks in VScode: Is there a way how I can hide a cell from showing up? I know it would be possible if I edit the metadata of the notebook, but I hope there is a better way.

edit: I found a way to automate the conversion with [`jupytext`](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext) and bash. You can find my proposed solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56722347/vscode-automating-conversion-of-python-file-to-jupyter-notebook-with-a-task/56753936#56753936)

Answer (score 0):

See that [Jupyter support in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support) has improved a lot. There is a command to import and an icon in the interface to export from Jupyter to Python:

[[image: Icon to export Jupyter to Python script]]

Unfortunately I can't find an option to automatically export the notebook to a Python script, you must manually export it.

Comment: Hey, I asked the same question on stackoverflow and also posted my workaround with a bash script. You can see it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56753936/11120993